# Comparar datas javascript!

Tags: javascript

Nesses meus dois *alert* tenho duas datas, a primeira data é a data que é pega do meu controle de data dateedit da devexpress.
O segundo eu criei uma variável e concatenei com get date, month e year.

Estou com problema para comparar a que eu concatenei com a data do controle pois estão em formatos diferentes. Como formatar a data em JavaScript pra comparar com aquela primeira data da imagem?

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Meu código:

```
function ValidaData(controleDataInicio, controleDataFinal) {

    var date = new Date();

    date = (date.getDate() + '/' +  (date.getMonth() + 1) + '/' + date.getFullYear() + ' 00:00:00');

    if (controleDataInicio.GetDate() < date) {

            alert(RetornaInternacionalizacao('AlertaData2'));
            controleDataInicio.SetValue(null);
    }  
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Você pode usar a biblioteca [MomentJS](http://momentjs.com/) para fazer operações com data no javascript.

Por exemplo:

```
if (moment($('[id$=_txtData]').val(), "DD/MM/YYYY").isBefore(Date())) { //regra aqui }
```

No site deles você encontra a documentação completa para todo tipo de operação, formato e regionalização com datas. Na minha opinião é a melhor biblioteca para trabalhar com datas em javascript, que sempre se mostrou problemático com esse tipo de operação.

Answer (score 3):

Uma vez que queres fazer uma comparação entre datas não é muito interessante colocar a tua Date nesse formato mas sim o contrário. Para comparares precisas de ter as duas datas como Date objects.

A mesma situação foi abordada [aqui](https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/Q510511). Esse componente efectivamente retorna um formato estranho.

Para tal vamos pegar na data que o teu componente retorna e transformar num objecto Date. O construtor da classe Date não reconhece essa string retornada pelo componente mas seria capaz de criar uma data no seguinte formato "Jan 01 2015". Para obter este formato dividimos a string com o metodo split e construimos uma string valida para o construtor. Ficaria assim o teu método:

```
function ValidaData(controleDataInicio, controleDataFinal) {

    var date = new Date();
    date = (date.getDate() + '/' +  (date.getMonth() + 1) + '/' + date.getFullYear() + ' 00:00:00');
    var dateElements = controleDataInicio.GetDate().split(" ");
    var newDate = new Date(dateElements[1] + " " + dateElements[2] + " " + dateElements[3]);

    if (newDate < date) {

        alert(RetornaInternacionalizacao('AlertaData2'));
        controleDataInicio.SetValue(null);
    }  
}
```